# Bash script loops infinitely

Tags: bash, unix

I was practicing with bash scripts and wrote this small script, which supposed to print all readable files that have sizes larger than 1GB.

```
#!  /bin/bash
find / -size +1G -readable
```

When I run it this way, it obviously starts printing tons of things. I was not able to terminate or interrupt the process using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>. Later I added a `&` in the end of the script, but it still won't run in the background.

Does anyone have an idea why it happens?

Comment: Any chance the find process was in uninterrupible sleep? If this is linux check `ps aux` and see if it is in D state. That might happen, for example, if you have a NFS mount but the server is unavailable.

Comment: I'm running linux on a ssh and a GUI, and I could not even access the ps table while the script running. Had to close the program and reconnect. Does the script itself look correct?

Comment: Open a second session to check. Nothing in your script should cause it to hang under normal circumstances.

Comment: Managed to kill it finally, after looking up the session number. I don't understand, though, why it wouldn't run on the background in first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing to the terminal takes time. When a program is printing faster than bash can keep up, hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't help because all of the output has already been added to the pipeline. You could be stopping `find` halfway through, but since it has already had so many hits, bash keeps printing what is in the pipeline even though you killed the process.

Adding & won't help either because your terminal session is still getting backed up by the IO. Just cause you run a process in the background doesn't mean bash isn't going to print the IO.

Here is a simple bash script. Run this with &, and you will still see 1s getting printed out.

```
while [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
do
    echo 1; sleep 1;
done
```

The main thing to try is re-directing IO to files.

```
find -------- 2> /dev/null
```

This removes the "Permission Denied" errors into /dev/null. If you run that script as a regular user, you are probably getting a lot of those errors.

```
find ---------- 1> find.txt
```

This will put the positive hits into a find.txt, so that you can go back and take your time reading the positive hits. And together,

```
find ---------- 2> /dev/null 1> find.txt
```